# Sobrecarga en C# (En una figura Triangulo)

Tags: c#, sobrecarga

tengo un pequeño problema, acabo de entrar en el tema de sobrecarga en C# donde estoy realizando una actividad sobre poner una herencia en las figuras (Cuadrado, circulo y triangulo) para sacar su area y perimetro, de ahi en el Triangulo tengo que aplicar la sobrecarga para que funcione con los tres tipos de triangulo que son: isosceles, escaleno y equilatero, sin embargo aun no lo tengo claro de desarrollarlo
donde solo tengo esta parte, mas sin embargo no es como deberia ser, si alguien podria orientarme se lo agradeceria mucho c:

```
namespace Tarea3Figuras
{
     class Triangulo:Figura
    {
        private int lado2;
        private int lado3;

        public int Lado2 {
        
            set {
                if (value < 0) {
                    lado2 = 0;
                }
                else{
                lado2=value;
                }
            }
            get {
                return lado2;
            }
        }

        public int Lado3 {
            set {
                if (value < 0)
                {
                    lado3 = 0;
                }
                else {
                    lado3 = value;
                }
            }
            get {
                return lado3;
            }
        }
        public Triangulo(int tbase, int altura) {
            Lado1 = tbase;
            Lado2 = altura;
        }
        public Triangulo(int L1, int L2, int L3) {
            Lado1 = L1;
            Lado2 = L2;
            Lado3 = L3;
        }
        public override float area()
        {
            return (Lado1 * Lado2) / 2.0F;
        }
        public override float perimetro()
        {
            return Lado1 + Lado2 + Lado3;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Pues primero debes establecer como se llama tu metodo que sobrecargaras, por ejemplo Area, para ello debes establecer, las varables que utilizaras para el area de triangulo solo necesitas Base y Altura. Este tema es basico asi que hay bastantes articulos con explicacion sencilla ejemplo: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/polymorphism

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!